# Screen tab completion

Tags: command-line, brainstorm

Is it possible to make the terminal behave like screen when it comes to tab completion? In screen, when you press tab, it gives the possible completions just below, but doesn't display the prompt again, instead, continues in the same prompt.

Comment: This is not the behavior of screen that I observe.

Comment: @January [This](http://i.imgur.com/NiRyz.png) is the behavior is observe - when I type "Do" tab, it shows me the options "Downloads" and "Documents" and remains at the same prompt, unlike the usual terminal, which shows the options, and goes to the next prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is shell specific behavior. The system to which you are logging in with ssh gives you `zsh` as your default shell, whereas in Ubuntu, the default shell is `bash`. Try it! Open a terminal and type `zsh`. The first time you run it, it will ask you for a configuration option. Then, presto, you have your desired behavior.

To make it permanently your login shell, open a terminal and type

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Next time you log in, zsh will be your default shell.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you for that, I thought it was specific to screen/